# JBOSS War Deployment not able to use mysqlds.xml

Tags: jboss, war

i have deployed a war application in jboss/server/default/deploy folder . The problem here is my application is not able to access the mysqlds.xml. When i tried to use jboss/server/default/jboss-web.deployer it is throwing an exception like "myDataSource is not bind".

this is my mysql-ds.xml(in server/default/deploy )

`

```
<jndi-name>MySqlDS1</jndi-name>

<use-java-context>true</use-java-context>

<connection-url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test</connection-url>

<url-delimiter>|</url-delimiter>

<driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>

<user-name>test</user-name>

<password>test</password>
```

`

it seems my problem is solved when i removed jboss-all-client and mysql connector jar to jboss/server/default/lib jboss-common.jar to jboss/lib

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste your xml please. Also, you can find a sample "mysql-ds.xml" in your jboss;

jboss\docs\examples\jca\mysql-ds.xml

Is the filename correct? Is there a naming convention that JBoss follow?

In your jboss-web.xml; jndi-name

```
<jndi-name>java:**/**MySqlDS1</jndi-name>
```

Can you get rid of the "/" and see if that works?

If still you get an error, then please paste your error logs as well

Comment: still it is same after removing /. There is no error when am using my war in deploy folder . There am facing the problem that **Connection Object that is returning is null **

Comment: I dont know why but your <use-java-context>true</use-java-context> is bugging me. Can you get it out and then test your web app. Also, what version of JBoss are you using?